# Strange.. UART accessing U1RXREG is not emptying buffer? PIC32

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, microchip

Not sure what's going on this PIC32 device, the ISR is only getting the first 8 characters (the size of the FIFO buffer) the first time it receives a string. Subsequent string arrivals cause an overrun error without reading anything in the ISR.

A couple things to note:-

1. The TX and RX are externally wired for loopback (TX->RX)
2. Flow control is implemented in hardware, so the ISR has time to read the buffer before more data arrives
3. Various combinations of manually toggling both the URXEN, OERR, RXIF, usart ON, RXIE, etc bits (including setting and then clearing) did not help. Flow control was only done after troubleshooting and it still did not fix the issue.
4. Using SRS vs Software for the ISR, changing to single vector interrupts did not change the outcome

It is as though reading from the U1RXREG resister does not get rid of the data, even though I tried to manually flush the data (see point #3).

Before sharing the code, these are the results:-

1ST PASS:

```
- "1234567890ABCDEF" is written with clear gap in the middle indicating that the flow control works
- "!!!!!!!\r\n"
- "12345678"
- "XXXXXXX\r\n"
```

2ND PASS (and every pass thereafter):

```
- "1234567890ABCDEF" is written with NO gap in the middle, indicating that the flow control isn't working anymore
- "OERR=1\r\n" indicating that OERR is set, even though flow control was used and all 8 bits in the buffer was read
- "!!!!!!!\r\n"
- <nothing>
- "XXXXXXX\r\n"
```

Mentioning again, various combinations of bit clearing & toggling were done to try fixing this, both in the ISR and outside of it but the result is always that after reading & printing the first 8 bits, nothing from the test string gets printed after.

CONTROLLER:- PIC32MK1024MCF064 @ 8MHz

CODE:-

```c
// DEVCFG3
#pragma config USERID = 0xFFFF          
#pragma config PWMLOCK = OFF          
#pragma config FUSBIDIO2 = OFF         
#pragma config FVBUSIO2 = OFF           
#pragma config PGL1WAY = OFF            
#pragma config PMDL1WAY = OFF        
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            
#pragma config FUSBIDIO1 = OFF         
#pragma config FVBUSIO1 = OFF           

// DEVCFG2
#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_1         
#pragma config FPLLRNG = RANGE_BYPASS  
#pragma config FPLLICLK = PLL_POSC      
#pragma config FPLLMULT = MUL_1         
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_2         
#pragma config VBATBOREN = OFF        
#pragma config DSBOREN = OFF          
#pragma config DSWDTPS = DSPS32       
#pragma config DSWDTOSC = LPRC         
#pragma config DSWDTEN = OFF          
#pragma config FDSEN = OFF              
#pragma config BORSEL = LOW            
#pragma config UPLLEN = OFF            

// DEVCFG1
#pragma config FNOSC = POSC        
#pragma config DMTINTV = WIN_127_128    
#pragma config FSOSCEN = OFF           
#pragma config IESO = OFF              
#pragma config POSCMOD = EC      
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF          
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD        
#pragma config WDTPS = PS1048576        
#pragma config WDTSPGM = STOP           
#pragma config WINDIS = NORMAL        
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             
#pragma config FWDTWINSZ = WINSZ_25     
#pragma config DMTCNT = DMT31          
#pragma config FDMTEN = OFF           

// DEVCFG0
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF             
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF            
#pragma config ICESEL = ICS_PGx2     
#pragma config TRCEN = OFF           
#pragma config BOOTISA = MIPS32        
#pragma config FSLEEP = OFF         
#pragma config DBGPER = PG_ALL        
#pragma config SMCLR = MCLR_NORM       
#pragma config SOSCGAIN = GAIN_2X       
#pragma config SOSCBOOST = OFF       
#pragma config POSCGAIN = GAIN_LEVEL_3  
#pragma config POSCBOOST = OFF        
#pragma config EJTAGBEN = NORMAL       
// DEVCP
#pragma config CP = OFF                

// SEQ
#pragma config TSEQ = 0xFFFF          
#pragma config CSEQ = 0xFFFF           



#include <xc.h>
#include <sys/attribs.h>

#include "p32mk1024mcf064.h"
#include "delay.h"
#include "usart_write.h"

#define USART1_BUFF_SIZE 100

volatile int USART1_index = 0; 
volatile char USART1_results[USART1_BUFF_SIZE];

int main() {
 
    __builtin_disable_interrupts();
    
    char TEST_STRING[] = "1234567890ABCDEF";
    char OERR[] = "OERR=1\r\n";



    char RX_PRE_string[]     ="!!!!!!!\r\n";
    char RX_POST_string[]     ="XXXXXXX\r\n";
    
    ANSELAbits.ANSA4 = 0;
    ANSELBbits.ANSB7 = 0;
    TRISAbits.TRISA4 = 1;
    U1RXR = 0x02; 
    RPB7R = 0b00001; 
    U1CTSR = 0x11;
    RPE15R = 0b0001; 

 
    INTCONbits.MVEC=1;
    PRISSbits.PRI6SS = 0b0001;
    

    

    while(U1MODEbits.ACTIVE == 1){
        asm("NOP;");
    }
        //****SETUP U1MODE BITS****     
    U1MODEbits.ON = 0;
    U1MODEbits.CLKSEL = 0b01;
    U1MODEbits.SLPEN = 0;
    U1MODEbits.OVFDIS = 0;
    U1MODEbits.SIDL = 1;
    U1MODEbits.IREN = 0;
    U1MODEbits.RTSMD = 0;
    U1MODEbits.UEN = 0b10;
    U1MODEbits.WAKE = 0;
    U1MODEbits.LPBACK = 0;
    U1MODEbits.ABAUD = 0;
    U1MODEbits.RXINV = 0;
    U1MODEbits.BRGH = 1;
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0b00;
    U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0;
    U1STAbits.MASK = 0x00;
    U1STAbits.ADDR = 0x00;
    U1STAbits.UTXSEL = 0b10;
    U1STAbits.UTXINV = 0;
    U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1; 
    U1STAbits.URXISEL = 0b11;
    U1STAbits.ADDEN = 0;
    U1STAbits.OERR = 0;
    U1BRG = 17;
    IPC9bits.U1RXIP = 6;  
    IPC9bits.U1RXIS = 0;     
    IFS1bits.U1RXIF = 0;  
    IEC1bits.U1RXIE = 1; 
    U1MODEbits.ON = 1;

  

    delay_ms(4000); 
    while(1){

        for(int i=0; i!=USART1_BUFF_SIZE; i++){
            USART1_results[i] = 0x00;
        }        
        USART1_index = 0;
        
        IFS1bits.U1RXIF = 0;  
        U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;        
        IEC1bits.U1RXIE = 1;  
        U1MODEbits.ON = 1;
        
        __builtin_enable_interrupts();
        UART1_Write_Text(&TEST_STRING);
        delay_ms(500);
        __builtin_disable_interrupts(); 
        IFS1bits.U1RXIF =0;
        IEC1bits.U1RXIE =0;
        U1STAbits.URXEN = 0;
        delay_ms(3500);
              
        if(U1STAbits.OERR == 1){    
            UART1_Write_Text(&OERR);
            delay_ms(4000);
        }

        UART1_Write_Text(&RX_PRE_string);
        delay_ms(4000);
        UART1_Write_Text(&USART1_results);
        delay_ms(4000);
        UART1_Write_Text(&RX_POST_string);
        delay_ms(4000);        
    }
    return 0;
}



void __attribute__((interrupt(IPL6SRS),at_vector(39), nomicromips)) USART1_ISR(void)
{ 
    if((U1STAbits.FERR == 1)||(U1STAbits.OERR == 1)){
        U1STAbits.OERR = 0;
        U1STAbits.URXEN = 0;
        U1STAbits.URXEN = 1; 
        IFS1bits.U1RXIF = 0;      
        asm("ERET;");
    }
    
     
    while((U1STAbits.URXDA == 1)||(U1STAbits.RIDLE == 0)){
        USART1_results[USART1_index] = U1RXREG;
        USART1_index++;
    }   
    IFS1bits.U1RXIF = 0;    
    asm("ERET;");
}
```

Comment: What is your intention with the `||(U1STAbits.RIDLE == 0)` inside your UART ISR? I can't see why you would want to continue trying to read U1RXREG based on the 'Receiver Idle' bit. You should only be reading U1RXREG if the URXDAbit is set.

Comment: Initial implementation was without this but it did not work either. @brhans